# Breeze with Parse.com Backend?

Tags: parse-platform, breeze

I am starting a new web / mobile project and I would like to use Breeze.js for data access and Parse.com for my backend provider. Does anyone have experience with hooking Breeze to Parse.com or know of any projects out there that are doing this already? I realize that Parse.com has their own APIs for data access but I am already familiar with Breeze and I would like to continue to use it if possible.

Comment: I don't know of an existing implementation.  You will need a [custom DataServiceAdapter](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/dataserviceadapters) to get breeze to work with parse.com's API.  The [ZUMO Adapter](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.labs/blob/master/breeze.labs.dataservice.azuremobileservices.js) is similar to what you will need.

Comment: You could use [AJAX](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/~ajax_interface.html) to consume [Parse REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide)